# Laravel regex for multiple patterns does not work?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I want my regex pattern to simply allow emails from bournemouth with > ac.uk domain
And emails from nhs with > .net or .uk
However I'm having a hard time trying to this to work, I've tried adding the separator to the regex and it doesn't work, and tried removing the 'i' but that is needed.

Regex: `'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'regex:/(.*)@(bournemouth)\.ac.uk/i | @(nhs)\.net|uk/i', 'unique:users'],`

Comment: Try `'regex:/.*@(?:bournemouth\.ac\.uk|nhs\.(?:net|uk))/i'` or just `'regex:/@(?:bournemouth\.ac\.uk|nhs\.(?:net|uk))/i'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
'regex:/.*@(?:bournemouth\.ac\.uk|nhs\.(?:net|uk))/i'
```

Or

```
'regex:/@(?:bournemouth\.ac\.uk|nhs\.(?:net|uk))/i'
```

**Details**

- `@` - a `@` char
- `(?:bournemouth\.ac\.uk|nhs\.(?:net|uk))` - a non-capturing group matching

  - `bournemouth\.ac\.uk` - a `bournemouth.ac.uk` string
  - `|` - or
  - `nhs\.(?:net|uk)` - `nhs.` followed with either `net` or `uk`.

Note the literal dots are escaped, there are no spaces inside the pattern between the alternatives, and the `i` flag is set only at the end of the regex.

Comment: Right okay makes much more sense thanks for breaking it down, I get quite overwhelmed with these regexes